# Real Root of a Polynomial on a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

can you give me some tips to solve this question? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way of looking at this would be to construct a second polynomial $Q(x)$ that is, essentially, the antiderivative of $P(x)$ (with a constant term of $C=0$). (Depending on where you are in your coursework, you don't have to say it's the antiderivative to $P$, just say "let $Q(x)$ be ..." It's equally valid.)

Thus, $Q'(x) = P(x)$. From there, apply the mean value theorem to $Q$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

That should be a sufficient nudge forward.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the polynomial
\begin{align}
f(x) = C_0 x+\frac{C_1}{2}x^2+\ldots+\frac{C_n}{n+1}x^{n+1}
\end{align}
and use Rolle's theorem.